# Magento TierPrice Not Showing Correctly - Database Issue?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I recently tried using a Mass Product importer to import tier prices (separated by customer group) and it totally messed up my database. Like your average dummy, I didn't back up the database beforehand. Now that I've learned my lesson on that front, I've got the database back into what seems to be decent shape except for one thing-- my Product View page shows the Normal Price while my Category Page shows the appropriate Tier Price.

I've looked at the code and it seems that both end up calling /template/catalog/product/price.phtml to display the price. I've tested changes with the code in price.phtml, view.html, list.html and I have searched high and low through the functions they call to find a way to fix it, but in reality this issue hadn't occurred until there was a database issue so anything I end up doing code wise would be a hack-- and even then I don't think I'm knowledgeable enough to make that happen very quickly.

I TRUNCATED catalog_product_entity_tier_price AND catalog_product_index_tier_price so that I could start fresh. This fixed the original issue where all of the prices displayed wonky no matter what customer type was viewing.

I read somewhere that List and View draw from different parts of the database-- is there any way to get whatever tables these are back in line and I have my site displaying properly?

Comment: Did you try reindexing Product Prices (System->Index Management) from magento backend.

Comment: Yeah I reindexed a few times. I actually had a backup of a normal product export that I ran through to make sure everything else (non Tier-Price) was in good shape then reindexed.